# Angular Js 1.x to display all the ng-model names in controller. In the form has more than 100 inputs

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJs 1.x want to print all the ng-Model names in controller. In my application form has more than 100 input fields. Then my application one of the part, I have to declare all the input names into server side even few variable value is empty. So if I get ng-model names easy way to declare the variables.
For Example :

```
<div controller="IndexController as form">
<form name="myform">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="form.name" name="name"/>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="form.email" name="email"/>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="form.mobile" name="mobile"/>    
</form>
</div>
```

Ouput: name, email, modile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're best wrapping your ng-model in a scope object.
For example:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="form.details.name" name="name"/>
<input type="text" data-ng-model="form.details.email" name="email"/>
<input type="text" data-ng-model="form.details.mobile" name="mobile"/>
```

A model is just an object with key:value properties.
You can use the `Object.keys` to get an array of all properties keys and iterate on them, like below..

```
var keys = Object.keys($scope.details);

for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
   console.log(keys[i]);
}
```

Comment: `form` is the scope. Note the _controller as_ syntax

Comment: Didn't notice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider you form model is like this:

```
let form = {"email": "abc@xyz.com", "fname": "abc"};
```

You can make use of `for ... in` loop.

> The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an
>   object. For each distinct property, statements can be executed.

```
for (let i in form) {
  console.log(form[i]);
}
```

OUTPUT

abc@xyz.com

abc